# How to generate a Jar with only class definitions and methods using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I've got a project and want to share an API that can be used for building a plugin for my application.

Now I don't want to share the full source code but only class definitions and member declarations without their body.

I've seen dependencies before that without downloading the sources the IDE I'm using already knows the structure. That is what I'm going for.

Comment: You might consider publishing a jar that only contains interfaces.

Comment: Care to elaborate how to do that? I don't see an option for that.

Comment: Split your project in two modules. One is the API, one is your implementation

Comment: Also, this is Java, not C. You don't have to ship source code to make your public APIs consumable (though it's often polite).

Comment: @chrylis Do you know how? Jah mentioned before using interfaces but I cannot convert 1200+ source files to interfaces.

Comment: Separate into a multi-module maven project. Build a parent pom, and then `myproject-api` and `myproject-impl`. Share `myproject-api`

Answer (score 0):

A jar file already does most of what you want, as it does, if not [obfuscated](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/), contain all the class and method names in a format that will be understood by any Java IDE.

The rest can be done by preparing and delivering a [javadoc jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html).

Comment: Does this javadoc jar tell the IDE for example Intellij how the classes and methods are?

Comment: a normal jar actually does that; the javadoc adds extra information above and beyond class  and method names/types.